# Slide contents from different div, hide one, show another

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a menu with `loadContent`, which load the page in div **#main**, so I can change only the content and the menu always stay.

```
<ul>  
<li class="page1"  onclick="loadContent('page1.php');">page1</li>  
<li class="page2"  onclick="loadContent('page2.php');">page2</li>  
<li class="page3" onclick="loadContent('page3.php');">page3</li> 
</ul>
```

How can I slide smooth this content, when I click one of the pages on the menu, may be right to left or top to bottom, so I can hide "old" page and show (push out) the "new" page.

Comment: post your related `loadContent` function too... anyways it looks like you want accordion....search for jquery ui accordion

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, there are some cool effects here http://jqueryui.com/effect/